# Is there a closed-form expression for Shapley value of glove game?

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, closed-form

Suppose we have a coalition game with transferable utilities, with $m$ players having a right-handed glove and $n$ players having a left-handed glove. The value of a coalition is equal to the number of complete pairs of gloves in it. Then the Shapley value for a player with a right-handed glove is given by:

$\frac1{(m+n)!}\sum_{i=1}^{m+n}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor i/2 \rfloor-1}(m+n-i)!(i-1)!\binom{m-1}{j}\binom{n}{i-j-1}$

Is there a simple (or at least easy to evaluate) closed-form expression for this?

If not, perhaps an approximation for large m,n?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by closed form. In principle the stated formula is a closed form. The parameter $m$ and $n$ are exogenous given variables determined by the glove game ($i,j$ are indices). Having these values you can directly calculate the Shapley value.

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt: I mean that the number of operations required is bounded as $m$ and $n$ vary. The formula isn't practical when $m$ and $n$ are in the millions; and it's too complicated, and providing little insight about how that value changes with $m$ and $n$. e.g., I'm looking for a formula like $n/(m+n)$ (of course this one is not correct). I'll accept factorial as an elementary operation, because it can be calculated with Stirling's formula.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are looking, in fact, for an approximation of the above formula for very large $m$ and $n$ for doing some differential calculus on the Shapley value.

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt: That's the general idea. Of course, if possible, I'd prefer an exact simple expression rather than an approximation.

Comment: One additional remark from a computational aspect. The largest $n$  that can be handled for the Stirling's formula on a 64-bit computer system is $170$ and not in the millions. From this point of view, I have some doubts what would be the benefit to have an approximation of at least second order for the above forumula at hand.

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt: That shouldn't be much of a problem, since you can just work in log space on the factorials as long as it is relevant; or arbitrary-precision arithmetic. Mathematica takes a second to calculate 100000! to full precision, but it would be difficult to repeat 10 billion times. (I also don't know for a fact that factorials would have to be involved).

Comment: I wrote a small Mathematica program to check the performance while incoperating the Stirling formula in the above formula for m=1000 and n=150, and the performance for the orginial formula was much better. Although, I don't think that this capture your question, if you are interest, I can make it avaiable upon request.

Comment: For $m=n$, the expression is $\dfrac12$.

Comment: For $m=1$, the expression is $\dfrac n{n+1}$

Comment: For $m=n-1$, the expression is very close to $\dfrac{a_n}{(m+n)!}~,~$ where $a_n$ is the sequence described [here](http://oeis.org/A246606).

Comment: @Lucian: Thanks, that's a good start. It's also a bit discouraging. I was hoping that at least for specific cases like $m=n-1$ we could have an exact expression, not just close to an OEIS sequence (which itself seems nontrivial to generate. Any ideas on how to, for example, generate a series expansion around $m=n$?

Comment: An illustrative example - in http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/raumann/pdf/The%20Shapley%20Value.pdf, section 2.2 example 5, he mentions the value with $n=10^6, m=n+1$. Any idea how he did that? These numbers seem too large for a brute force calculation.

Comment: I am afraid that combinatorics is not exactly my strong suit... to put it mildly. :-$)$

Comment: Have you tried cross-posting this question over at [*Math Overflow*](http://mathoverflow.net) ? I suggest that you also include a link to the original, and mention the fact that it got no answer here in three months.

Comment: @Lucian: I'll consider it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find the article "The asymptotic shapley value for a simple market game" by Liggett, Lippman and Rumelt (2007) interesting and relevant for your question.

They analyse a market game with $b$ buyers (in your case, this would be the $m$ players having a right-handed glove) who each seek to purchase 1 unit of an indivisible good form $s$ sellers (the $n$ players with a left-handed glove), each of whom has $k$ units to sell. I think that if $k=1$, this game coincides with the glove game. If $V(b,s)$ denotes the notes the Shapley value for a seller in this game, it turns out that $$V(b,s) = \frac{1}{b+s} \sum_{i=0}^{s+b-1} \sum_{2j > i} \frac{\binom{b}{j} \binom{s-1}{i-j}}{\binom{s+b-1}{i}} \quad . $$
Suppose $b, s \to \infty$, so that $b/ks = b/s \to \alpha$. If $\alpha = 1$, and we assume that $\frac{ks-b}{\sqrt{b+s}} \to u $, then $$V(b,s) \to \frac{k^{2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{u^{2} + kx^{2}}e^{-x^{2}/2} dx \quad \text{if } u \geq 0. $$
There's a similar formula for the case in which $u \leq 0$.